# Error while mongorestore - assertion: 17370 Restoring users and roles is only supported for clusters with auth schema versions 1 or 3, found: 5

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am trying to restore a folder which was created using `mongodump`, and I am using `mongorestore`. But there is an error:

assertion: 17370 Restoring users and roles is only supported for clusters with auth schema versions 1 or 3, found: 5

How can I solve this error and successfully restore?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to restore the individual databases one at a time using the --db parameter.

Comment: I've faced with this issue when used 2.x version of mongod, while my mongodump was done by 3.6.x version of mongod